# MSSQL BIT_COUNT (Hammingdistance)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there any function similar to the MYSQL `BIT_COUNT` function in MSSQL? I want to create a very simple Hammingdistance function in MSSQL that i can use in my selects.

Here is what i have for MYSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `HAMMINGDISTANCE`(`hasha` BIGINT, `hashb` BIGINT)
    RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN 
    BIT_COUNT(hasha^hashb)
```

Comment: Use SQL CLR. Does it have to be [Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)? How about [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), there are many example available. Eg. http://levenshtein.blogspot.com/

Comment: I need Hamming for comparing images by generated perceptual hashes. I will give SQL CLR a try thank you. :)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu - Why does he need SQL CLR if all he needs is to count the bits? See my answer for more details.

Comment: @dcp: because CLR is going to run circles around T-SQL code counting bits

Comment: @Remus Rusanu - Did you benchmark it to find out? I'm not really convinced.

Comment: @Reemus Rusanu - Also, you might want to see this link: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1630934-bit-counting.html Someone tried using an extended C++ stored procedure but actually found that T-SQL was faster. The moral of the story is...always benchmark and never assume :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just write your own bit_count code in T-SQL? There's no need to use SQL CLR if all you need is to count the number of set bits in a bigint. Here is an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bit_count
(
   @pX bigint
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @lRet integer
   SET @lRet = 0
   WHILE (@pX != 0)
   BEGIN
      SET @lRet = @lRet + (@pX & 1)
      SET @pX = @pX / 2
   END   
   return @lRet   
END
GO
```

Also, here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6c09/5) you can try to see this function in action.

Be advised that this algorithm only works on non-negative bigints. If you are looking for an algorithm that works on negative bigints, see [this link](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1630934-bit-counting.html).

Comment: How are you doing the `hasha^hashb` that is the input to this function? SQL Server [doesn't support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx) bitwise operations between `bigint`.

Comment: His question was how to do the bit_count, but you bring up a good question. What exactly does carrot operator do in MySQL? I thought it was exclusive or, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as XOR is the MySQL exclusive or operator (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor). I googled MYSQL carrot operator but didn't get any hits, so I'm confused. Do you know what that operator does?

Comment: I thought XOR as well. But actually on testing `bigint` *does* seem to work after all. Books online only mentions `int`/`tinyint`/`smallint` but `DECLARE @B BIGINT = 9223372036854775807;SELECT @B ^ 0` does in fact seem to work fine.

Comment: @Martin - Yes, good point, it does seem to work fine with bigints. I just tried this and it gave proper result as well: select cast(9223372036854775807 as bigint) ^ cast(123421349333 as bigint). However, I'm still not sure if carrot operator does exclusive or in MySQL since I can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: carrot operator should do that in mysql as this is what i was expecting as i wrote it years ago... but anyways it worked so i guess it do so.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a HAMMINGDISTANCE using the provided code by dcp and it seems to work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HAMMINGDISTANCE](@hasha BIGINT, @hashb BIGINT)
    RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pX BIGINT
   DECLARE @lRet integer
   SET @lRet = 0
   SET @pX = @hasha ^ @hashb
   WHILE (@pX != 0)
   BEGIN
      SET @lRet = @lRet + (@pX & 1)
      SET @pX = @pX / 2
   END   
   return @lRet   
END

GO
```

Comment: Glad it worked, but note that the algorithm I used doesn't work on negative numbers. See my edit if you need an algorithm for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any function similar to the MYSQL BIT_COUNT function in
> MSSQL?

Yes, there is [`BIT_COUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/bit-count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The catch is that it is only available from SQL Server 2022 so was not available when you asked your question but will eventually become useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_hamming_distance]
(
    @a     BIGINT,
    @b     BIGINT
)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @c BIGINT = @a ^ @b
    RETURN 
    CASE 
         WHEN @c IS NULL
              THEN NULL
         ELSE CASE 
                   WHEN @c < 0 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
              END
              +
              CASE 
                   WHEN @c & 0x4000000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x2000000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x1000000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x800000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x400000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x200000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x100000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x80000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x40000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x20000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x10000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x8000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x4000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x2000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x1000000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x800000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x400000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x200000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x100000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x80000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x40000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x20000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x10000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x8000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x4000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x2000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x1000000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x800000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x400000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x200000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x100000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x80000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x40000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x20000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x10000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x8000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x4000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x2000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x1000000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x800000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x400000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x200000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x100000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x80000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x40000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x20000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x10000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x8000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x4000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x2000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x1000 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x800 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x400 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x200 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x100 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x80 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x40 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x20 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x10 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x8 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x4 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x2 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
          +
          CASE 
               WHEN @c & 0x1 > 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
    END
END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Consider adding an explanation for how this solves the questioner's problem.